# What all can a valid approximation algorithm access?

Tags: algorithms, approximation

For example can an approximation algorithm call a subroutine which is solving a NP-Hard problem? (like say its trying to find the longest path in some graph as an intermediate step) Is that allowed?

Comment: What do you think? In general, any algorithm may use any other algorithm as subrouting, and even itself.

Answer (score 3):

Depends. Typically, with "approximation algorithms" people understand algorithms that run in polynomial time and return a possibly non-optimal solution (with a formal guarantee on the solution quality). In this definition, **no**, you can't spend exponential time solving an NP-hard problem.

On the other hand, nothing is forcing you to consider polynomial time algorithms that return non-optimal solutions. In fact, it is interesting to consider algorithms that take exponential time, and still return non-optimal solutions. See for instance [1, 2].

---

[1] [Cygan, Marek, Lukasz Kowalik, Marcin Pilipczuk, and Mateusz Wykurz. "Exponential-time approximation of hard problems." arXiv preprint arXiv:0810.4934 (2008).](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.4934.pdf)

[2] [Cygan, Marek, Łukasz Kowalik, and Mateusz Wykurz. "Exponential-time approximation of weighted set cover." Information Processing Letters 109, no. 16 (2009): 957-961.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019009001719)

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what complexity you want your algorithm to have. For example, if you're trying to approximate an **EXP**-hard problem then a polynomial algorithm that uses an **NP** oracle might be acceptable; if you're trying to approximate something that's only **NP**-hard, using an **NP** oracle more than once would be potentially more expensive than just solving the problem exactly.